# MiniMagick affecting Amazon S3 file that comes before resize code

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rmagick, minimagick, ruby-grape

I'm attempting to upload the full size image that comes from a post, then thumbnail it and put the thumbnail on S3. However, I'm running into a strange issue where the my resize code seems to be affecting the full size image, even though S3 should be storing it prior to any resize occuring. Here is a snippet of code illustrating it...

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store(fullPath, open(params[:photo][:tempfile]), BS.config[:service][:aws][:bucket], :access => :public_read)

  thumbnail = MiniMagick::Image.open(params[:photo][:tempfile].path)
  thumbnail.combine_options do |c|
    c.resize('200x200^')
    c.gravity('center')
    c.crop('200x200+0+0')
  end

  AWS::S3::S3Object.store(thumbnailPath, thumbnail.to_blob, BS.config[:service][:aws][:bucket], :access => :public_read)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you call `store` before doing the resize, there's no guarantee the code for the resize does not begin before the code for storing has finished, and since there's network latency involved and the [docs for S3Object](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#M000044) specifically say that larger files (of which image files could surely be classed) will get sent up in chunks, it's quite possible you're modifying a file that hasn't yet been sent.

Whatever the reason, the simple answer is to make a copy of the file and resize that.

Comment: I ended up using Paperclip since it offered what I needed in a more streamlined package. I am marking this as correct because this is the correct answer to my original question.

Comment: @nullfox glad you got it sorted.